# Icons Control | Elementor

Tags: wordpress, icons, elementor

what does {{{ iconHTML.value }}} stands for in the _content_template?
the render is working fine but there's a reference error: iconHTML is not defined.
This is from the elementor controls documentation but i cant seem understand what should I substitute in {{{ iconHTML.value }}}

```
add_action( 'elementor/widgets/widgets_registered', function( $widget_manager ) {
        class Icons_Control_Test_Widget extends \Elementor\Widget_Base {
            public function get_name() {
                return 'icons_test_widget';
            }
    
            public function get_title() {
                return __( 'Icons Test Widget', 'text-domain' );
            }
    
            protected function _register_controls() {
                $this->start_controls_section(
                    'section_icon',
                    [
                        'label' => __( 'Icon', 'text-domain' ),
                    ]
                );
    
                $this->add_control(
                    'icon',
                    [
                        'label' => __( 'Icon', 'text-domain' ),
                        'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::ICONS,
                        'default' => [
                            'value' => 'fas fa-star',
                            'library' => 'solid',
                        ],
                    ]
                );
    
                $this->end_controls_section();
            }
    
            protected function render() {
                $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();
                ?>
                <div class="my-icon-wrapper">
                    <?php \Elementor\Icons_Manager::render_icon( $settings['icon'], [ 'aria-hidden' => 'true' ] ); ?>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
    
            protected function _content_template() {
                ?>
                
                <div class="my-icon-wrapper">
                    {{{ iconHTML.value }}}
                </div>
                <?php
            }
        }
        // register widget
        $widget_manager->register_widget_type( new Icons_Control_Test_Widget() );
    } );
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Sadly, Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The elementor itself does not say what that means. For me, **iconHTML** does not work at all and I have to create the appropriate element myself. My solution doesn't cause logs either.

```html
<div>
    <i aria-hidden="true" class="{{{ settings.icon_control_name.value }}}"></i>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT**
Just use renderIcon from elementor.helpers.renderIcon. Eg.

```html
<div class="icon_wrapper">
    <# var iconHTML = elementor.helpers.renderIcon( view, settings.icons_controller, { 'aria-hidden': true }, 'i' , 'object' ); #>
    <!--- And now it's working --->
    {{{ iconHTML.value }}}
</div>
```

Thanks for @rotemee from issue https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/15707

Comment: I opened issue on github https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/15707 for this problem

Comment: Docs is updated but this still not working for me:
```html
<div class="my-icon-wrapper">
    {{{ settings.icon.value }}}
</div>
```